# TapGestureRecognizer is not working for the Image component?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm using the back icon with the gesture to navigate to the previous page. Following are the code I'm using in the xaml and xaml.cs file.

In Xaml:

```
    <Image 
      Style="{StaticResource HeaderImageStyle}" 
      Source="ic_back_arrow_xx.png">
      <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
            Tapped="SigninPage"
            NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
        </TapGestureRecognizer>
     </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
```

In Xaml.cs:

```
    public async void SigninPage(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
```

In App.xaml :

```
<Style x:Key="HeaderImageStyle" TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="WidthRequest">
        <OnIdiom
            x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
            Phone="25"
            Tablet="37"
            Desktop="25"/>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="HeightRequest">
        <OnIdiom
            x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
            Phone="25"
            Tablet="37"
            Desktop="25"/>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When clicking on the back arrow the corresponding event is not firing. My Xamarin.Forms version is 4.8.0.1821. Is there any such defect reported for this version?

Comment: Did you test it on iOS?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Same issue is there on IOS and Windows parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS it will be an expected effect as the **UIImageView** on native iOS will block tap event in default . So we need to set it by using custom renderer.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using xxx.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(Image),typeof(MyImageRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyImageRenderer:ImageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                Control.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

For the same issue on UWP , you could add a relevant tag so that people can help you better .

### Update

Because you display an image in the layout and set `VerticalOptions` to FillAndExpand. It'll work fine if removing the image. If you want to add background image for the page, you could set `BackgroundImageSource` for the contentPage.

```
<ContentPage ...
    BackgroundImageSource="ic_new_background_xx.png">
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        Margin="10,20,10,0"
        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Image 
            Source="ic_back_arrow_xx.png">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                            Tapped="SigninPage"
                            NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
            <Image 
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                    Source="ic_app_logo_new_xx.png"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <ScrollView>
            ...
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: What about the android part?

Comment: If it doesn't work on all platforms , you could share your sample .

Comment: I will share a sample soon

Comment: Sample link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XqiE4dOEa7ilasZynlBYetShXy-0DfKR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67003309/xamarin-forms-hide-and-show-password-feature-is-not-working-for-entry