# Xamarin forms: Hide and show password feature is not working for entry

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have implemented the hide and show password feature for the entry component. It is not working initially, but after one hide and show, it starts working. The icons are changing but the password is not showing. This issue is only on the android platform.

My code:

**Xaml:**

```
<StackLayout Padding="3" Orientation="Horizontal">

    <local:CustomEntry
        x:Name="password_entry"
        IsPassword="True"
        Placeholder="Password"
        Style="{StaticResource LoginEntryStyle}"/>

    <Image 
        x:Name="password_icon"
        Style="{StaticResource LoginEntryImageStyle}" 
        HorizontalOptions="End"
        Source="ic_hide_password_xx.png">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="PasswordIcon_Clicked"
                NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
            </TapGestureRecognizer>
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
</StackLayout>
```

**Xaml.cs:**

```
bool showPassword = true;
private void PasswordIcon_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (showPassword)
    {
        password_icon.Source = "ic_show_password_xx.png";
        password_entry.IsPassword = false;
        showPassword = false;
    }
    else
    {
        password_icon.Source = "ic_hide_password_xx.png";
        password_entry.IsPassword = true;
        showPassword = true;
    }
}
```

Instead of the bool variable, I have tried with `password_entry.IsPassword`, but no luck. I have uploaded a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XqiE4dOEa7ilasZynlBYetShXy-0DfKR/view?usp=sharing) for reference.

Comment: why did you initialize the `showPassword` bool in true ?

Comment: @FabriBertani For handling the initial click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with triggers and check only the `IsPassword` property for the entry

```
<StackLayout Padding="3" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <local:CustomEntry
        x:Name="password_entry"
        IsPassword="True"
        Placeholder="Password"
        Style="{StaticResource LoginEntryStyle}"/>
    <Image
        Style="{StaticResource LoginEntryImageStyle}" 
        HorizontalOptions="End">
        <Image.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
                TargetType="Image"
                Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference password_entry}, Path=IsPassword}"
                Value="True">
                <Setter
                    Property="Source"
                    Value="ic_show_password_xx" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger
                TargetType="Image"
                Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference password_entry}, Path=IsPassword}"
                Value="False">
                <Setter
                    Property="Source"
                    Value="ic_hide_password_xx" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Image.Triggers>
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="PasswordIcon_Clicked" />
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
</StackLayout>
```

And on your code behind just assing inverted bool to the entry `IsPassword` property on gesture recognizer tap

```
private void PasswordIcon_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    password_entry.IsPassword = !password_entry.IsPassword;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a potential issue, you could raise it on github.

## Workaround

```
 if (showPassword)
            {
                password_icon.Source = "ic_show_password_xx.png";
                password_entry.IsPassword = false;
                password_entry.IsPassword = true;
                password_entry.IsPassword = false;
                showPassword = false;
            }
            else
            {
                password_icon.Source = "ic_hide_password_xx.png";
                password_entry.IsPassword = true;
                showPassword = true;
            }
```